# Git checkout of Visual Studio Solution copy folder structure to other branch

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.8.5
I have a playground repository where I realized some solution.
I have also 3 branches
If in branch1 I create a new solution XX then I close Visual Studio then from powershell perform:

- git add .
- git commit -a -m "..."
- git push
- git checkout branch2

The folder structure (without any file) of the solution XX is copied to the branch2.
I would not this, do you have a solution, please?

Comment: Are you sure the directory is empty? No hidden files that are untracked in the folder you think is empty?

Comment: Yes, no hidden files no system files

Comment: Suppose you do this outside of Visual Studio. From the command line, create a folder, put a file in it, commit it, switch to another branch. The directory should be deleted. Does that work for you?